# Spring Config Server : get secrets from vault with specific path

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am trying to get my microservices configuration from a config server connected to 2 sources : git and vault (for secrets). I have the config bellow:
in the config-server:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: git, vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
          kvVersion: 2
        git:
          order: 2
          uri: git@gitlab.git
```

and in the client side in the bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service-name

  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      token: //token
      label: dev
```

But in my vault i have the path like this :

```
secret/cad
     |--my-service-name
```

When i make my secret directly in `/secret/my-service-name` i can access my secrets, but how can i configure acces to secrets in : `/secret/cad/my-service-name`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your Custom configuration Class that implements VaultConfigurer where you can override to your custom path

@Configuration
Public class CustomVaultConfiguraton implements VaultConfigurer {

```
 @override
 public void addSecretsBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configures){

 configures.add("customPath");
```

}
}

add above configuration class in spring.factories
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\packagename.CustomVaultConfiguration